# Latex Listing Format Error

Tags: listings, bold, italic

I'm having some difficulty with getting the `listings` package to properly format code snippets. In particular, it does not consistently **bold** keywords and *italicize* comments.

The code I am currently using is:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=C,
  morekeywords=    {*,rule,endrule,module,endmodule,Action,interface,endinterface,method,endmethod,case,endcase,matches},
  showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
  showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
  showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular  underscores
  %frame=single,                   % adds a frame around the code
  tabsize=2,                      % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
  breakatwhitespace=true,        % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={code},label={lst:code}]
//  1: t1 = Py - Qy
rule op1_ctrl(oper == 4'd1 && fire_cond);
pa0.loadAddSub(0, 5, 7, 1, vecCnt);
pa1.loadAddSub(0, 5, 7, 1, vecCnt);
pa2.loadAddSub(0, 5, 7, 1, vecCnt);
pa3.loadAddSub(0, 5, 7, 1, vecCnt);
endrule

//  2: t2 = Px - Qx
rule op2_ctrl(oper == 4'd2 && fire_cond);
pa0.loadAddSub(0, 4, 6, 2, vecCnt);
pa1.loadAddSub(0, 4, 6, 2, vecCnt);
pa2.loadAddSub(0, 4, 6, 2, vecCnt);
pa3.loadAddSub(0, 4, 6, 2, vecCnt);
endrule
\end{lstlisting}
```

For example, my code snippet should be displayed like this:

> *//   1: t1 = Py - Qy*
>
> **rule** op1_ctrl(oper == 4'd1 && fire_cond);
>
> pa0.loadAddSub(0, 5, 7, 1, vecCnt);
>
> pa1.loadAddSub(0, 5, 7, 1, vecCnt);
>
> pa2.loadAddSub(0, 5, 7, 1, vecCnt);
>
> pa3.loadAddSub(0, 5, 7, 1, vecCnt);
>
> **endrule**
>
> *//    2: t2 = Px - Qx*
>
> **rule** op2_ctrl(oper == 4'd2 && fire_cond);
>   pa0.loadAddSub(0, 4, 6, 2, vecCnt);
>
> pa1.loadAddSub(0, 4, 6, 2, vecCnt);
>
> pa2.loadAddSub(0, 4, 6, 2, vecCnt);
>
> pa3.loadAddSub(0, 4, 6, 2, vecCnt);
>
> **endrule**

What I actually get is:

> *//   1: t1 = Py - Qy*
>
> **rule** op1_ctrl(oper == 4'd1 && fire_cond);
>
> pa0.loadAddSub(0, 5, 7, 1, vecCnt);
>
> pa1.loadAddSub(0, 5, 7, 1, vecCnt);
>
> pa2.loadAddSub(0, 5, 7, 1, vecCnt);
>
> pa3.loadAddSub(0, 5, 7, 1, vecCnt);
>
> endrule
>
> // 2: t2 = Px - Qx
>
> rule op2_ctrl(oper == 4'd2 && fire_cond);
>   pa0.loadAddSub(0, 4, 6, 2, vecCnt);
>
> pa1.loadAddSub(0, 4, 6, 2, vecCnt);
>
> pa2.loadAddSub(0, 4, 6, 2, vecCnt);
>
> pa3.loadAddSub(0, 4, 6, 2, vecCnt);
>
> **endrule**

Any ideas why this is happening or how I can fix it?

Comment: I know that people will be asking for a minimum failing example:o) try to delete one line at a time, and see if the problem persist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) uses `'` as string delimiters. That's why everything between the two single quotes in your code is typeset without any formatting. One way around this is to identify a `literate` replacement text:

```
\literate=*{'}{'}{1}
```

This replaces `'` with `'` of width `1` , doing virtually nothing, but replacing the syntax change associated with `'`, as in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\begin{document}
\lstset{language=C,
  morekeywords={*,rule,endrule,module,endmodule,Action,interface,endinterface,method,endmethod,case,endcase,matches},
  showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
  showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
  showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular  underscores
  %frame=single,                   % adds a frame around the code
  tabsize=2,                      % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
  breakatwhitespace=true,        % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  literate=*{'}{'}{1}
}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={code},label={lst:code}]
//  1: t1 = Py - Qy
rule op1_ctrl(oper == 4'd1 && fire_cond);
pa0.loadAddSub(0, 5, 7, 1, vecCnt);
pa1.loadAddSub(0, 5, 7, 1, vecCnt);
pa2.loadAddSub(0, 5, 7, 1, vecCnt);
pa3.loadAddSub(0, 5, 7, 1, vecCnt);
endrule

//  2: t2 = Px - Qx
rule op2_ctrl(oper == 4'd2 && fire_cond);
pa0.loadAddSub(0, 4, 6, 2, vecCnt);
pa1.loadAddSub(0, 4, 6, 2, vecCnt);
pa2.loadAddSub(0, 4, 6, 2, vecCnt);
pa3.loadAddSub(0, 4, 6, 2, vecCnt);
endrule
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```